# Kivy (Python) minimum_height behaves inconsistently

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, minimum

Has anyone else found that the minimum_height value is sometimes ignored.  Here is some sample code.  At times it functions just as expected at other times it does not.  I can find no pattern to this behavior.  To recreate the issue please run the code, close it and run again.  It usually takes me no more than 3 tries to get the issue to appear.  What you should see is sometimes the buttons at the bottom of the screen take on the minimum height that matches the font size and at other times the buttons take on the default height of 100.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.app import runTouchApp


main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")

filler_label = Label(text='Space Filler  Label',halign='center',valign='middle',size_hint=(1,None))

filler_layout = GridLayout(cols=1,size_hint=(1,1))
filler_layout.bind(minimum_height=filler_layout.setter('height'))

filler_layout.add_widget(filler_label)

button_layout = GridLayout(cols=3,size_hint_y=None)
button_layout.bind(minimum_height=button_layout.setter('height'))

button1 = Button(text='Button1',size_hint_y=None)
button1.bind(texture_size=button1.setter('size'))
button2 = Button(text='Button2',size_hint_y=None)
button2.bind(texture_size=button2.setter('size'))
button3 = Button(text='Button3',size_hint_y=None)
button3.bind(texture_size=button3.setter('size'))

button_layout.add_widget(button1)
button_layout.add_widget(button2)
button_layout.add_widget(button3)

main_layout.add_widget(filler_layout)
main_layout.add_widget(button_layout)


runTouchApp(main_layout)
```